# FirebaseAuth OTP Authentication Not working on Mobile Devices Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

#### Not receiving OTP on Mobile But Works on Web.

I'm trying to authenticate my users mobile number as usual by firebase auth .
The Problem is I am **not able to receive otp** on emulator as well as my physical device .
But whenever i run my app on chrome using this command :

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

I enter the same mobile number but i am receiving otp with this and not on mobile devices.
I can't figure out why its happening .
Also the otp process completes sucessfully when I'm using test phone numbers offered by firebase.

Following is my code for the otp verification:

```
void signInWithPhone(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
try {
  await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        print('Before-signing in with credential');
        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        debugPrint('After-signing in with credential');
      },
      verificationFailed: (e) {
        debugPrint(e.message.toString());
        debugPrint(" THIS IS ERROR ${e.message}");
        showSnackbar(context: context, content: e.message!.trim());
        throw Exception(e.message);
      },
      codeSent: ((String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        debugPrint('Code sent');
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, OTPScreen.routeName,
            arguments: verificationId);
      }),
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        debugPrint('Auto retrieval timeout');
      });
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  debugPrint(e.message!);
  debugPrint(e.toString());
  showSnackbar(context: context, content: e.message!);
}
```

}

And I'm calling the above function in the following ways :

```
void sendPhoneNumber() {
try {
  debugPrint('VerificationCompleted');
  String phoneNumber = phoneController.text.trim();
  if (country != null && phoneNumber.isNotEmpty) {
    ref
        .read(authControllerProvider)
        .signInWithPhone('+${country!.phoneCode}$phoneNumber', context);
  }
} catch (e) {
  showSnackbar(context: context, content: 'Fill the phone number field');
}
```

}

I get the following errors :

```
 Play Integrity Token fetch failed, falling back to Recaptcha-9: Integrity API error (-9): Binding to the service in the Play Store has failed. This can be due to having an old Play Store version installed on the device.
E/zzb     ( 4546): Ask the user to update Play Store.
E/zzb     ( 4546):  (https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#CANNOT_BIND_TO_SERVICE).
D/EGL_emulation( 4546): app_time_stats: avg=632.60ms min=33.58ms max=1231.62ms count=2
W/System  ( 4546): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor( 4546): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
E/OpenGLRenderer( 4546): Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
E/FirebaseAuth( 4546): [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
E/zzb     ( 4546): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher( 4546): sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17@cbdc15b
D/EGL_emulation( 4546): app_time_stats: avg=1098.10ms min=1098.10ms max=1098.10ms count=1
W/System  ( 4546): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor( 4546): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
E/FirebaseAuth( 4546): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
D/FirebaseAuth( 4546): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +917387251914, error - This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter( 4546): Compat change id reported: 247079863; UID 10192; state: DISABLED
I/flutter ( 4546): This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
I/flutter ( 4546):  THIS IS ERROR This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
```

Steps I performed till now :

1. Configured the correct SHA keys and added it to firebase
2. Upgraded to the latest versions of dependencies.
3. Browse every possible question and answer on here as well as on google.

Comment: I fixed the above error in this way:

First of all you need **SHA keys** .
For that I ran the  
 `./gradlew signingReport `

command in the terminal. 

It returned the sha keys for my app , These sha keys are the ones you want to include in the firebase console.
**NOTE**: The SHA keys generated in the above way only worked for me , I had also generated sha keys by using keytool and another method but that didn't worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the above error in this way: First of all you need **SHA keys** . 
For that I ran the  `./gradlew signingReport`  command in the terminal. 
It returned the sha keys for my app, These sha keys are the ones you want to include in the firebase console.
 **NOTE**: The SHA keys generated in the above way only worked for me , I had also generated sha keys by using keytool and another method but that didn't worked !